# If statement to product data if both statements are true

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to produce an outcome if both rows in two different tables match, but I am having a hard time trying to make it work. Can someone please tell me if I am missing something.. Thank you in advance

**Note: my connections are in an included file and both tables are in the same database

```
<html>      
<p>Pending Documents</p>

        <?php


            $sql ="SELECT * FROM `forms`";


            if ($_SESSION['user_name'] == $row["username"]){ ?>

            <p><a href="">SUTA Document</a></p>

            <? }else { ?>

            <p>No Pending Documents</p> 
        <? } ?>
</html>
```

Comment: Which two tables? Where do you execute the query and fetch a row?

Comment: I take it from that question I am missing something, I will look into that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should solve it with mysqli. Here is a working snippet:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . mysqli->connect_error;
}

if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `forms`")) {

    while ($obj = $result->fetch_object()) {
        if ($_SESSION['user_name'] == $obj->username){ ?>

        <p><a href="">SUTA Document</a></p>

        <? }else { ?>

        <p>No Pending Documents</p> 
    <? }
    }

    $result->close();
}

$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to make the query :P